# Getting the value of selected option that comes from jquery to update the form action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

i'm having a problem getting the selected value in jquery and stick it to the submit button. here's my code to better understand the problem.

As you can this is my Html form.

```
<form method = "get" action = "main/folder/">
    <div id="select-vehicle">
        <select>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type = "submit" value = "submit">TEST</button>
</form>
```

and here's my working jquery .

```
var workers = ["car1", "car2", "car3"];
        for(var i=0; i< workers.length;i++)
    {
    //creates option tag
      jQuery('<option/>', {
            value: workers[i],
            html: workers[i]
            }).appendTo('#select-vehicle select'); //appends to select if parent div has id dropdown
    }
```

Thank you very much!

**Update**

Whenever i get selected value i want to put that value end of form action

example : `"main/folder/SelectedValue"`

Comment: i dont see any selecting of value in your OP it is setting dynamic option to the select

Comment: yes i tried populating it dynamically hoping to get the value too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
  $('button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = $( "select" ).val();
    $('form').attr('action', 'main/folder/' + value);
  });
```

Add this code to your script and you will get selected value as a part of your form action attribute.

Comment: it works!! but i need to get it to the url. at the end of my action page '/main/folder/VALUE SELECTED'

Comment: uhh dumb question @dhilt how do i do that.

Comment: I will do that update by myself, you need to accets current edit and then accept my edit. Also, I updated my answer to satisfy your task with form action.

Comment: hmmm it's not working. nothing's happening when i hit submit. tried removing the previous value of my action in html. same result.

Comment: Oh.. nothing happens due to `event.preventDefault();`. You may throw it away or submit your form manually via `$( "form" ).submit();`

Comment: BAAAM!!! it's now fully working! thanks man. last question. i can do an relative url here right?

Comment: Sure, you can. The host of the request (in case of relative action path) would be the same as the host of the site where this html/js running. E.g. localhost if you are running the stuff locally.

Comment: Thank you very much! you've been a big help1

Comment: Good luck! PS you still didn't approve the post pending change. I'd recommend to change the title to "Getting the value of selected option that comes from jquery to update the form action" to be more specific for future visitors.